# I'm a beginner programmer and I have a problem with the slider,

Tags: javascript

slides do not appear when you click on currentSlides and do not scroll when you click prev and next
here is the html:

```js
let slideIndex = 1
showSlides(slideIndex);

const dot1 = document.querySelector('#dot1')
dot1.onclick = currentSlides(1)

const dot2 = document.querySelector('#dot2')
dot2.onclick = currentSlides(2)

const dot3 = document.querySelector('#dot3')
dot3.onclick = currentSlides(3)

const dot4 = document.querySelector('#dot4')
dot4.onclick = currentSlides(4)

const prev = document.querySelector('.prev')
prev.onclick = plusSlides(-1)
const next = document.querySelector('.next')
next.onclick = plusSlides(1)

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n)
}

function currentSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n)
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__item")
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot")

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", " ")
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active"
}
```

```css
.slider__page {
  position        : absolute;
  bottom          : 0;
  margin-left     : 17%;
  right           : 0;
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : row;
  justify-content : space-between;
  width           : 83%;
  }
.slider__name {
  font-size       : 18px;
  color           : #4e4e4e;
  text-transform  : uppercase;
  border-top      : solid 3px #4e4e4e;
  padding-top     : 15px;
  padding-bottom  : 15px;
  transition      : .2s linear;
  cursor          : pointer;
  display         : inline-block;
  transition      : 0.2s linear;
  width           : 23%;
  text-decoration : none;
  margin-right    : 18px;
  margin-left     : 10px;
  text-align      : center;
  }
.slider__name:hover {
  color        : rgb(196, 196, 196);
  border-color : rgb(196, 196, 196);
  }
.container1 {
  position         : fixed;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  z-index          : 2000;
  background-color : #000000;
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  display          : none;
  transition       : .2s linear;
  }
.slider__item {
  min-height                 : 100vh;
  -webkit-animation-name     : fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration : 1s;
  animation-name             : fade;
  animation-duration         : 1s;
  }
.slider__text {
  font-size   : 30px;
  padding     : 8px 12px;
  color       : #fff;
  position    : absolute;
  margin      : 0 auto;
  font-weight : 700;
  top         : 8%;
  max-width   : 300px;
  margin-left : 15%;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.slider__text2 {
  font-size   : 30px;
  padding     : 8px 12px;
  color       : #fff;
  position    : absolute;
  margin      : 0 auto;
  font-weight : 700;
  top         : 8%;
  max-width   : 300px;
  right       : 15%;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.img__slider {
  width      : 85%;
  max-height : 90%;
  position   : absolute;
  top        : 5%;
  right      : 7.5%;
  left       : 7.5%;
  bottom     : 5%;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor           : pointer;
  position         : absolute;
  top              : 50%;
  width            : auto;
  margin-top       : -22px;
  margin-right     : 7.5%;
  margin-left      : 7.5%;
  padding          : 16px;
  color            : #fff;
  font-weight      : bold;
  font-size        : 18px;
  transition       : 0.6s ease;
  border-radius    : 50%;
  background-color : transparent;
  font-size        : 24px;
  text-decoration  : none;
}
.next {
  right         : 0;
  border-radius : 50%;
  }
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color : rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.8);
  color            : #fff;
  }
.dot__div {
  width          : 85%;
  margin         : 0 auto;
  position       : fixed;
  bottom         : 5%;
  right          : 0;
  left           : 0;
  display        : block;
  flex-direction : row;
  }
.dot {
  text-decoration : none;
  width           : 100%;
  display         : inline-block;
  width           : 23%;
  font-size       : 18px;
  color           : #ffffff;
  text-transform  : uppercase;
  border-top      : solid 3px #bdbdbd;
  padding-top     : 15px;
  padding-bottom  : 15px;
  transition      : .2s linear;
  z-index         : 1000;
  cursor          : pointer;
  transition      : 0.3s linear;
  text-decoration : none;
  margin-right    : 10px;
  }
.active {
  font-size      : 18px;
  color          : rgb(71, 71, 71);
  border-color   : rgb(69, 69, 69);
  text-transform : uppercase;
  padding-top    : 15px;
  padding-bottom : 15px;
  transition     : .2s linear;
  z-index        : 1000;
  cursor         : pointer;
  display        : inline-block;
  transition     : 0.3s linear;
  width          : 23%;
  }
.dot:hover {
  color        : rgb(71, 71, 71);
  border-color : rgb(71, 71, 71);
  }
.end__slider {
  color        : #fff;
  font-size    : 50px;
  float        : right;
  margin-right : 2%;
  cursor       : pointer;
  margin-top   : 1%;
  transition   : .2s;
  }
.end__slider   :hover {
  color        : rgb(160, 160, 160);
  }
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: .4 }
  to   { opacity: 1  }
  }
@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: .4 }
  to   { opacity: 1  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider__page">
  <div id="slider__name1" class="slider__name">history of our company</div>
  <div id="slider__name2" class="slider__name">consult</div>
  <div id="slider__name3" class="slider__name">our projects and results</div>
  <div id="slider__name4" class="slider__name">project examples consult</div>
</div>
<div id="container1" class="container1">
  <div id="slider" class="slider__div">
    <div id="end__slider" class="end__slider">&times;</div>
    <div id="slide__item" class="slider__item">
      <img class='img__slider' class="slider__img" src="img/view-of-the-green-mountains-and-hills-at-sunset_545689-8154.avif" alt="">
      <div class="slider__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio ex modi, cum deleniti sequi fuga inventore, placeat excepturi soluta eaque commodi beatae aut aspernatur magnam ad iure! Maiores, ad! Facilis.</div>
      <div class="slider__text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias atque itaque expedita animi natus autem consequuntur dolorem excepturi, debitis adipisci?</div>
    </div>

    <div id="slide__item" class="slider__item">
      <img class="img__slider" src="./img/brz01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider__text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis porro sunt magni atque ut quis odit nostrum vel unde. Nulla autem minima velit tenetur nemo.</div>
      <div class="slider__text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias atque itaque expedita animi natus autem consequuntur dolorem excepturi, debitis adipisci?</div>
    </div>

    <div id="slide__item" class="slider__item">
      <img class="img__slider" src="./img/toratau.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, porro. Quaerat quia officiis id, suscipit labore consectetur repellat impedit vel!</div>
      <div class="slider__text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias atque itaque expedita animi natus autem consequuntur dolorem excepturi, debitis adipisci?</div>
    </div>

    <div id="slide__item" class="slider__item">
      <img class="img__slider" src="./img/ліс.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="slider__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequuntur asperiores, dolore, ducimus a tenetur ad aspernatur minus distinctio doloribus tempore non veritatis obcaecati nulla.</div>
      <div class="slider__text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias atque itaque expedita animi natus autem consequuntur dolorem excepturi, debitis adipisci?</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev">&#10094</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095</a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="dot__div">
      <a id="dot1" class="dot active">history of our company</a>
      <a id="dot2" class="dot active">consult</a>
      <a id="dot3" class="dot active">our projects and results</a>
      <a id="dot4" class="dot active">project examples consult</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to unpack html into js, ​​because the html page is loaded in preweb but it still doesn’t work.
Most likely something with the showSlides function, because the console sees other functions

Comment: Although I want to rewrite your code, the problem that you are having is your onclick isn't correct. It should be something like `dot4.onclick = function(){currentSlides(4)}` Otherwise it is running on the loading of the page

Comment: or `dot1.onclick = e => currentSlides(1);`  don't forget any semicolons ! or use strict mode !

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a little mistake:
for the onclick function, use this syntax:

```
dot1.onclick = function() {currentSlides(1)}
```

Then, your container1 is set to "display: none;" (i don't know if you know or not)

Note:
to remove a class from an element, use this:

```
dots[i].classList.remove('CLASS_NAME')
```

Instead of this:

```
dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", " ")
```